# Hide/show two div based on jpg button selection

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a div with text and a separate div with a jpg image on a web page.

There are six (jpg) buttons in different areas on the web page.

When I select btn1.jpg, I would like text1.html and image1.jpg to load into the two div's.

When I select btn2.jpg, I would like text2.html and image2.jpg to replace the content of the div.

When I select btn3.jpg, I would like to have text3.html and image3.jpg load into the div's.

and so forth...

When one initially lands on the page, I would like to have the text and image associated with btn1.jpg loaded in the divs by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/gFHnh/ that should do what you want. I've just done 2 buttons with 2 sets of text and images but you can just add more html buttons, the JavaScript will deal with as many buttons as you like.

Note that no text loads as text1.html and text2.html doesn't exist for me but should work for you. Also I've used some example images from the web just to show it works.

**HTML**

```
<button id="button1" class="textImageChanger" data-image="http://www.transformerhair.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/test.jpg" data-html="text1.html">Button1</button>
<button class="textImageChanger" data-image="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/KWF_Test.png" data-html="text2.html">Button2</button>

<div id="textDiv"></div>
<div id="imageDiv"><img src=""/></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function LoadText(link) {
    $("#textDiv").load(link);
}

function LoadImage(image) {
    $("#imageDiv img").attr("src", image);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    LoadText("text1.html");
    LoadImage($("#button1").data("image"));

    $(".textImageChanger").click(function() {
        LoadText($(this).data("html"));
        LoadImage($(this).data("image"));
    });
});
```

​

Comment: Please bring your code into the answer, in order that the answer can still be useful when (not 'if') JS Fiddle next falls over.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  If I could trouble you for a couple adjustments. I would like to load my own jpg button (btn1.jpg, btn2.jpg, ect.) Also, when I load your code into my website and select btn2, the page refreshes and btn1's info loads into the 2 div.  Thank You!

Comment: @GeorgeAdis Do you mean you'd like the buttons to be images? Not sure why the button is refreshing the page, have you included jQuery? Do you have a link to your site that I could look at?

Comment: You can see the design frame I am trying to code on my website here (www.mychemistry.us.com/testpage1.aspx). I placed notes for you on the page. Thanks for taking the time to help a rookie out!

Comment: @GeorgeAdis I'm a little confused how you want it to work. I thought you just had 1 div for the text and one for the image and the content of these swap as you click different buttons like this http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/gFHnh/3/

Comment: You only mentioned button1 and button3, can you confirm that it is all 8 buttons that should change the text and image?

Comment: Yes Sir, each time you select one of the 8 jpg buttons, both the text and image change at the same time. Each of the 8 buttons has 1 text file and 1 image file associated with it.  For example, selecting button 7 loads the text and image for button 7.  The loaded text appears on the left and the image on the right in the shaded box above the buttons.

Comment: @GeorgeAdis Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/gFHnh/4/. I've applied the code in the original jsFiddle to the HTML on your site.

Comment: The code you wrote works perfectly and it is exactly what I needed.  Thank you for taking the time to help me.